# netcat working on localhost but not from remote host

Tags: linux, netcat

I have two machines (Machine1 & Machine2) on the same subnet. Machine1 has a tool installed that returns some data. for example if I run the following command, it returns some data.

```
printf "get:info\nend\n" | nc localhost 1234
```

However if do the same on Machine2, of course changing localhost to machine1, nothing happens. Any Idea what can be the problem?

```
printf "get:info\nend\n" | nc machine1 1234
```

Comment: Do a `ss -tlnp | grep 1234` on `machine1`. Does the tool listen on more than the local host ?

Comment: When I do the command mentioned, nothing happens. there is no info for that port.

Comment: first do just `ping`. then if it is OK, run `tcpdump` on machine 2 and check establishing a TCP connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating alot I finally managed to find the reason why I was not able to communicate  to the other machine on the specific port.

Iptables setting in my machine1 was not allowing machine1 to listen. I turned off of the iptables and everthing worked fine.

But its not a good idea to turn off the iptables. So for the next step I allowed port 1234 for machine1.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1234 -j ACCEPT
```

You can find more information about iptables on the link below:

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo
```