# Python Socket Chat Program Not Work in Remote System

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, chat

I have a python chat program server.py and client.py. And it works in my local system, but when I try to connect to a remote host like [koding.com](http://koding.com) ubuntu-vm or [cloud9](https://c9.io) ubuntu-vm it does not work.

I cannot reach the remote client across the web.

this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26040814/netcat-working-on-localhost-but-not-from-remote-host) suggests what some of my issues are.

My objective is to chat using internet not local area network

Here is chat server.py

```
import socket
import thread

HOST = ''               
PORT = 4444                      
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))

while True:
  s.listen(1)
  conn, addr = s.accept()
  print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if data[:4] == "exit":
        print 'Parted by', addr
    else:
        conn.send(data),
    if not data:
        break
    print data
conn.close
```

Here is chat client.py

```
import socket
getHOST = (raw_input('Enter the Host: '))
print getHOST
HOST = getHOST
PORT = 4444        
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

NICK = raw_input('Welcome, Enter your name: ')

while True:
  MSG = raw_input('>> ')
  MSG = NICK + ': ' + MSG
  if MSG[5:] == "exit":
    break
  s.send(MSG)
  data = s.recv(1024)
 print data  
s.close()
```

Comment: *Does not work* is no use! Please give the exact error instead of letting others guess what could have happened

Comment: in 2015, I suggest you use Python 3 :)

Comment: If your app works locally, but not from a remote system, chances are you need to open access to port 4444. Looks like cloud9 is running on Google cloud, so you might be out of luck there (they only support a few particular services). Koding VMs are hosted on AWS and they claim that all of their ports are open. Maybe your local network has trouble with port 4444?

Comment: @MadWombat thanks yes cloud 9 firewall is problem

Answer (score 4):

Your `server.py` shouldn't be even working locally, since it contains bugs.

- You must handle each incoming socket connection in a separate thread.
- You must call `s.listen(1)` only once, not in an infinite loop.

I suggest that you change your `server.py` as follows:

```
import socket
import thread

def handleChat(conn, addr):
    print 'Connected by', addr

    while 1:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if data[:4] == "exit":
            print 'Parted by', addr
        else:
            conn.send(data),
        if not data:
            break
        print data
    conn.close


def main():
    HOST = ''     
    PORT = 4444
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(1)

    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        thread.start_new_thread(handleChat, (conn, addr,))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

then put it on your server machine, say `example.com`, and run it. It should work now, as I tested and it did.